# Adding images into array of an Android Application

Tags: android, arrays

I want to display the images in my Application added to my "raw" folder of the Eclipse as it gets started.

How do I add those particular images to an Array and rotate the loop until all the Images are displayed?

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: specify what you mean with "the images". Images from the Web? Images from Sd Card? Images from Resources? if from web or sd card: How will your application know which images to display.

Comment: @Patrick Boss- Sorry Patrick Boss I have added those images into my raw folder of the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Android's frame animation. I think it does exactly what you want.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation

Comment: Add your images to the res/drawable directory and setup a frame animation XML file as explained in the link above.